# Action method didn't work with [HttpPost] attribute in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model, compiler-errors, asp.net-mvc-5

To delete data in `asp.net MVC 5` with `Razor Engine`, I wrote this code that works fine . However, I want to give it `[HttpPost]`  attribute, but if I add that, the action doesn't work.

Could anyone help me? What's the problem?

I have just one action named `delete` , I don't need another `Delete` action with `[HttpGet]`  attribute. 
How can I fix it?

**Repositories.cs**

```
public bool Delete(int id, bool autoSave = true)
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = db.Carousels.Find(id);
            db.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted;
            if (autoSave)
                return Convert.ToBoolean(db.SaveChanges());
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Admin controller**

```
public ActionResult DeleteCarousel(int id)
    {
        CarouselRepositories blCarousel = new CarouselRepositories();
        blCarousel.Delete(id);
        return View("ShowCarousel", blCarousel.Select());
    }
```

**ShowCarousel.cshtml**

```
@model IEnumerable<NP1.Models.Carousel>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "ShowCarousel";
Layout = "~/Views/Admin/AdminLayout.cshtml";
}


 <table class="table">
 <tr>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarouselSubject)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarouselInfo)
    </th>
    <th>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CarouselImage)
    </th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarouselSubject)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarouselInfo)
    </td>
    <td>
        @*@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CarouselImage)*@
        <img style="width:300px; height:200px;" src="~/Images/Carousel/@item.CarouselImage" />
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.CarouselID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCarousel", new { id = item.CarouselID })
    </td>
</tr>
 }

</table>
```

Comment: Your `Delete()` method is `[HttpGet]` by default. If you want it to be hit when you submit a form, you need to mark it with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: I mark it , but it didn't work ! , should I change my delete method ? @StephenMuecke

Comment: No, a `Delete()` method should be a POST (its changing data). If its not being hit, the your view is incorrect. You need to show it.

Comment: I updated my post , I don't have any view for delete data , it's true ?! @StephenMuecke

Comment: You need to replace `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", .... )` with a form and a submit button

Comment: I Sorry I don't know how do it . I added `@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "DeleteCarousel", new { id = item.CarouselID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure to delete it ?')" })
      ` but it didn't work yet . could you please give me an example ? I don't have any idea to how write Form in table :/ , Sorry @StephenMuecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark you method with the `[HttpPost]` attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeleteCarousel(int id)
{
  ....
}
```

and change the view to use a form rather than an `ActionLink()`

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
  <tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(m => item.CarouselSubject)</td>
    ....
    <td>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("DeleteCarousel", "yourControllerName", new { id = item.CarouselID }, FormMethod.Post))
        {
          <input type="submit" value="Delete" /> // style it look like a link if you want
        }
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

If you also want a confirmation message before deleting, add the following jquery script (the form submit will be cancelled if the user clicks `Cancel` or closes the dialog without clicking `OK`)

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  return confirm('Are you sure to delete it?');
})
```

Comment: Just noticed from your last comment that you also want a confirmation message - I will update the answer a little later with the jquery code to handle this.

Comment: Yeah you're right I need confirmation message too  . Thank you again